# windows powershell change text color of flags

Tags: powershell

I recently installed the Windows [ColorTool](https://github.com/Microsoft/Console/tree/master/tools/ColorTool) and have been playing around with it. I'm using it with the [iTerm color schemes](https://github.com/mbadolato/iTerm2-Color-Scheme) but am running into some color conflicts.

[image]

That line is supposed to say `.\colortool -b .\schemes\.OneHalfDark.itermcolors`, but the `-b` flag is currently the same color as the background. How do I change the color of just the flags?

Comment: PSReadline does the syntax coloring [see this SU link](https://superuser.com/questions/676140/how-to-set-colors-in-psreadline-in-powershell)

Comment: is there something similar for just the command prompt, instead of powershell?

Comment: Do you refer to colortool or PSReadline ?

Comment: something like PSReadline for the regular command prompt

Comment: Aside from `doskey` and the [new console hotkeys](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/Windows10GetsAFreshCommandPromptAndLotsOfHotkeys.aspx) I'm not aware of anything comparable to PSReadLine.

Comment: PowerShell is far better to `cmd.exe` in nearly every conceivable way. Switch.

Comment: lol I wish I could but for certain work-related reasons I cannot :(

Comment: What work-related reasons?

Comment: Please explain the work related reasons. I spend a fair bit of time explaining to businesses the advantages of switching to PS and the disadvantages of not switching...

Comment: not too sure on the implementation details, but we have some old (legacy?) scripts that only seem to run on cmd. I've tried them on PS and whatever those scripts are supposed to do, they don't do it correctly

Comment: given the complexity of the scripts, I think it's probably more worth my time to just go with cmd for now

Comment: PowerShell can run `cmd.exe` scripts by spawning `cmd /c`. That's not a reason not to switch to PowerShell.

Answer (score 4):

I was running into the same issue - it's that the default color of the flags is darkgray. I used the PSReadlineOption to change it

e.g.

Set-PSReadlineOption -TokenKind Parameter -ForegroundColor Cyan

This only works for the current powershell window, so I assume you will need to add it to the powershell profile for continuous use or just run this cmdlet everytime you use powershell